# Any javascript linter able to detect non-existing class method?

Tags: javascript, eslint, static-analysis

Eslint doesn't seem able to catch that `something2` doesn't exist.

I think I could use Typescript but this is for a huge project not using TS for now.

```
class Someclass {
  something() {
    console.log("test");
  }
}

const sc = new Someclass();
sc.something2();
```

Comment: You could try to use [Flow](https://flow.org/) Install it and add `// @flow` as the first line.

Comment: No, this is what a typechecker does. A linter doesn't catch these.

Comment: How would a checker know if `sc.something2 = () => undefined;` was added before `sc.something2()` was executed?